# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Interfaz y Clase Abstracta en java?

Tags: java, clase-abstracta

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre **interfaz** y **clase abstracta** en java? A la hora de usarlas, por qué preferir una Interfaz a una clase abstracta y viceversa y en qué caso es mejor evitar una o la otra.

Con esta pregunta busco saber en qué casos de la vida real es mejor  utilizar una o la otra.

Answer (score 27):

Existen varias diferencias entre una clase abstracta y una interfaz:

1. Una clase abstracta puede heredar o extender cualquier clase (independientemente de que esta sea abstracta o no), mientras que una interfaz solamente puede extender o implementar otras interfaces.
2. Una clase abstracta puede heredar de **una sola** clase (abstracta o no) mientras que una interfaz puede extender varias interfaces de una misma vez.
3. Una clase abstracta puede tener métodos que sean abstractos o que no lo sean, mientras que las interfaces sólo y exclusivamente pueden definir métodos abstractos.
4. En java concretamente (ya que has puesto la etiqueta Java), en las clases abstractas la palabra `abstract` es obligatoria para definir un método abstracto (así como la clase). Cuando defines una interfaz, esta palabra es opcional ya que se infiere en el concepto de interfaz.
5. En una clase abstracta, los métodos abstractos pueden ser *public* o *protected*. En una interfaz solamente puede haber métodos públicos.
6. En una clase abstracta pueden existir variables `static`, `final` o `static final` con cualquier modificador de acceso (*public*, *private*, *protected* o *default*). En una interfaz sólo puedes tener constantes (`public static final`).

En definitiva utilizar una u otra depende de tus necesidades. Yo en todos los años que llevo programando en Java sobre todo, apenas he utilizado las clases abstractas más que una o dos veces. En cambio las interfaces se utilizan mucho cuando trabajas con interfaces gráficas por ejemplo. Uno de los usos más comunes es para crear aplicaciones que hagan uso del concepto de hebras para ejecutar procesos que consumen más tiempo de CPU. Esto se hace mediante la interfaz [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) de Java, por poner uno de los innumerables ejemplos para los que se utilizan las interfaces.

En definitiva, es decisión tuya utilizar una clase abstracta o una interfaz. Si necesitas programar una clase de la que vayan a heredar otras pero que esas otras clases que heredan, compartan alguna funcionalidad (ejemplo: clase abstracta -> Persona. Clases que heredan -> Alumno, Profesor... Todas pueden tener un atributo nombre y métodos *get* y *set* de este atributo que hagan lo mismo), en ese caso te recomiendo que utilices una clase abstracta. En caso contrario, interfaz.

Comment: La respuesta es buena pero no contempla la implementación *por defecto* que se puede añadir a las interfaces desde Java 8. La respuesta de @Einer ayuda a completar la información.

Answer (score 10):

Las clases abstractas a diferencias de las interfaces, pueden tener constructores, implementaciones de metodo por defecto y solo se pueden heredar 1 sola vez de ellas 1 sola vez:

```
public abstract class Producto {

   private int precio;

   public Producto(int precio){
     this.precio = precio;
   }

  public int getPrecio(){
     return this.precio;
  }

   public abstract String getName();

}

public class Banana extends Producto{

   public Banana(){
      super(200);
   }

   @Override 
   public String getName(){
     return "banana";
   }
}
```

Aunque en java 8, se permiten las implementaciones por defecto, estas no pueden contener constructores.

En el caso de las interfaces, si se puede implementar de múltiples de ellas:

```
public class MiClase implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, Runnable {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {}

   @Override
   public void onTouch(View view) {}

   @Override
   public void run(){}
}
```

Esto permite emular la herencia multiple:

```
MiClase miClase = new MiClase();

new Thread(miClase).run();
elementoVista.setOnClickListener(miClase);
elementoVista.setOnTouchListener(miClase);
```

Las interfaces se les conoce como un contrato. Esto porque te obligan a la implementacion de sus metodos lo que le asegura a toda logica de negocio que todo objeto que implemente de ella, tendra el acceso a los metodo definidos en la misma.

Mientras que las clases abstractas son mas utilizadas para objetos de tipo base. Es como la principal en la jerarquia en un conjunto de objetos que comparten el mismo padre.

Answer (score 4):

Desde que Java 8 introdujo las implementaciones por defecto en las interfaces, la diferencia a la hora de usarlas se ha diluido mucho, pero principalmente es conceptual:

- Cuando una clase hereda de otra clase (abstracta o no), estás definiendo **qué es**, pasas de una idea abstracta a una concreción. Además, estás definiendo una relación entre clases.
- Cuando implementas una interfaz, estás definiendo **cómo se comporta**, estás cumpliendo un contrato. No implica ninguna relación con ninguna clase.

Ejemplos:

- Tenemos dos clases que cumplen las interfaces Comparable y Serializable. Una puede ser la clase String y la otra puede ser mi clase Usuario, que es un Java Bean que es parte de mi modelo de datos. No tienen nada en común, pero sabes que ambas pueden ser introducidas en un TreeSet o guardadas como datos en un fichero.
- Un ejemplo de clase abstracta muy conocida es HibernateDaoSupport: Haciendo que tus DAO hereden de ella, ya estás diciendo que tu clase es un DAO y que tiene ya una serie de métodos generales que te ayudarán a realizar consultas, pero no qué consultas se pueden realizar, eso te lo dirá la interfaz que implemente (si existe, algo habitual en la inyección de dependencias)

Answer (score 1):

Una clase abstracta es una clase dónde solamente declaras los métodos que se van a implementar. Es decir, sería como declarar variables, solamente declaras métodos se que implementarán.

Una interfaz es un tipo de clase abstracta. La funcionalidad de las interfaces es precisamente ser de interfaz a su implementación. Es decir que siempre que vas a instanciar una clase en el mail debes de hacerlo hacia la interfaz.

```
public interface Figura {
    public int getBase();
}

public class DefaultFigura implements Figura {
    private int x;

    public int getBase(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

Y en tu main debes de instanciar la interfaz. Este se hace como buena práctica.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tenemos clases que deben implementar un comportamiento idéntico, el método que implementa en el comportamiento se puede llevar a una clase abstracta.

Si una clase va a tener un mismo método pero con distintas implementaciones, estos métodos se pueden definir en una interfaz.

En una interfaz todos los métodos son públicos y no se define nunca la implementación de los métodos.

En una clase abstracta, se pueden tanto definir la implemetación de métodos como sólo el método a implementar, dejando la implementación a las clases que hereden de la clase abstracta.

Se puede HEREDAR de una clase abstracta y se puede IMPLEMENTAR una o más interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

En lo posible, evitar las clases abstractas.

La respuesta general sería:

Usar interfaces para definir tipos abstractos con un conjunto de miembros de tal manera que se puedan usar de una manera conocida.
Clases abstractas para lo mismo, pero con la posibilidad de compartir parte de la implementación.

El resultado de tener una estructura de clases estricta, se hace sentir en los productos especialmente en el mediano/largo plazo.

Elimina la fluidez (requiere ponerse a pensar dónde encaja lo que quiero expresar, en el orden general de las abstracciones del programa; esto es muchas veces un ejercicio espurio especialmente cuando se quiere desarrollar un concepto a nivel de prueba).
Genera clases intermedias.
Obliga a implementar asuntos en clases derivadas, sólo para el soporte de las clases base.
Requiere muchas veces la implementación de métodos, propiedades o a veces grandes conjuntos de ellos, sin valor (sabiendo que nunca serán llamados).
Impide la libre elección de conjuntos a implementar.