# Interfaz y clase

Tags: clase-abstracta, interfaz

¿Las clases tanto abstractas como concretas tienen interfaces?

Comment: No repitas tu pregunta. En su defecto, modifica la original para que sea valida. No sabria que estas preguntando aca, ya que tu duda es teorica y podria llevar a que la pregunta sea basada en opiniones.

Comment: ¿Interfaz abstracta? ¿Eso existe? Querrás decir la diferencia entre una interfaz y una clase abstracta.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez   ¿Interfaz se refiere a las clases? No se si la pregunta la han formulado mal.

Comment: Existen interfaces , clases abstractas y clases concretas. Tu pregunta no queda clara. ¿Qué es lo que quieres saber? La pregunta es una mezcla entre los tres términos. Comienza por [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107742/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-interfaz-y-clase-abstracta-en-java) que es muy similar a lo que quieres saber, y luego poco a pocos ve leyendo artículos sobre qué es una interfaz, y luego te centras en las diferencias. Acabo de googlear los términos y hay un montón de recursos allá afuera. Comienza realizando tú mismo una exploración.